# undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

when i comment the following code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

     // var data1= "<%=[@properties.map {|c| {time:c.time.strftime("%H").to_i , speed:c.speed}}].to_json%>"


    //var data=JSON.parse(data1.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));

    //alert("dataset-------------------"+data);
</script>
```

Following error is showing.Why this error occur after i commented the code.While removing comments following error also occurring.

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass):
        48: <div id="bar-demo" align="center">
        49: <script type="text/javascript">
        50: 
        51:  // var data1= "<%=[@properties.map {|c| {time:c.time.strftime("%H").to_i , speed:c.speed}}].to_json%>"
        52: 
        53: 
        54: //var data=JSON.parse(data1.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
      app/views/static_pages/show.html.erb:51:in `_app_views_static_pages_show_html_erb__413296487_31443192
```

'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring when `ActionView` is trying to evaluate the embedded Ruby.  Anything outside of `<%= ... %>` or `<% ... %>` has no bearing on any errors that might occur at this stage.  In particular the `//` has nothing to do with anything.  Those comments would only have an effect if the embedded Ruby were successfully evaluated by `ActionView`, the generated HTML document was sent to the client's browser by the controller, and then the HTML gets rendered/JavaScript gets executed by the browser -- only then would the comments have an effect, namely skipping setting the `data1` variable.

Your problem is that at the time the template is being rendered, the instance variable `@properties` is `nil`.  Do you have something like a `StaticPagesController` with a `show` action?  In that action do you set `@properties` anywhere?

Comment: yes i also rectify the problem.in the page load @properties will be nil.its contains value only if i select some data from dropdown.when i added conditions the error got solved :-)